# xml Regex matching the whole xml file

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext

I need a regular expression that given the following XML, will give me all the products (productos) that have 'Bebidas' as a category (categoria), and I have to do this in Sublime Text, so only have the option to use a regular expression (no dedicated XML parser allowed):

XML File [www.ethgf.com/electricos.xml](http://www.ethgf.com/electricos.xml)

I have a problem when I use `(?s)<producto>(.+?Bebidas.+?)<\/producto>` because it highlights almost all the XML (the first 'producto' tag through the last tag closure).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1

Comment: now you have 2 problems

Comment: Why don't you use a parser instead of regular expression?

Comment: Could you let us know what exactly do you want to highlight? "name1", "name2"??? Or is this arbitrary text?

Comment: @SeanBright and of course http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/582278

Comment: I want to highlight <product>
    <name>name1</name>
    <category>Drinks</category>
    <ref>HM511123</ref>
</product>

Comment: If you only can do this in Sublime, why not write a Python plugin and `import xml`? Seems much easier than mucking around with regexes...

Comment: Parsing XML using regular expressions is like cutting your fingernails with garden shears. Use the proper tool for the job: in this case, an XML parser and XPath.

Comment: @cbeltrangomez: Just a suggestion for future posts - do not use "xml" and "regex" tags together, they tend to clash often :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is about selecting the whole `<product>` nodes, you can use the following regex:

`(?s)<product>(?:\s*<(\w+)>[^<]*?<\/\1>\s*)*?\s*<category>Drinks<\/category>(?:\s*<(\w+)>[^<]*?<\/\2>\s*)*?\s*<\/product>`

It will highlight all `<product>` nodes that contain *Drinks* category, even if the nodes are not following some strict order:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that not all the nodes have the same order in the entries as well as there are other products with more nodes containing other information.

Comment: @cbeltrangomez: I updated the answer. I guess there are no "orphan" text nodes somewhere in between those you provided? If there no such words, this should work.

Comment: This one is working for me in ST3 using the data provided in the question. @cbeltrangomez Please post **relevant** example data in your question. Someone could write an answer to match your data, then you come back and say "*That's not really my data, actually it includes this and this, as well.*" That's called moving the goalposts, and is severely frowned upon here. Give a [Minimal Complete Working Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, so people can answer it as-posed, without relying on extra comments from you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm kind of new using stackoverflow, I've changed the question and the original file is in www.ethgf.com/electricos.xml.

Comment: @cbeltrangomez thanks for clarifying things. I'll ask again, as you haven't addressed it yet - is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a parser? As I alluded to in my comment above, you could easily write a Python plugin (or external Python program) to parse your file for a desired attribute, and return whichever data you're looking for, or delete the containing node if that's what you want to do. This could be accomplished in ~5-10 lines with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) in a fraction of the time it's taken to answer this question.

Comment: Hi, sadly the answer didn't work, maybe because my file is larger when I try to use that regex, sublime stops working. I want to use a regular expression for 2 reasons, first, I don't know how to make the python plugins and second I really want to learn about regex, I thing thats very useful when you are coding. Thanks for all the support

Comment: @cbeltrangomez: I see. You can split such files with 3rd party tools that split by specific number of bytes, and then process by chunks. You might lose a couple of nodes, but will get at least some results..

Comment: @cbeltrangomez: Since the question is not about parsing large files using Sublime Text, I think you can accept my answer, and ask another one about how to implement the `lxml` or any other XML parser for the tool (do not forget to post the outcome of your efforts).